# Xamarin android unable to assign text value to edit text

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I am new to mobile development. I am working on android in xamarin using visual studio 2015. For now i am following a [sample code](http://www.androidcodec.com/xamarin-sqlite-database-example-android/) and doing the same as described in it.

I am getting an exception when i try to assign a `text` value to a `edit text` in my `update` layout. Bellow is the code in which i am assigning the values to `edit text`

```
void List_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        click_Employee = e.Position + 1;
        ICursor c = dbHelper.getSingleEntry(click_Employee);
        c.MoveToFirst();
        name = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME));
        email = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_EMAIL));
        phone = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_PHONE));
        designation = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_DESIGNATION));
        dName.Text = name;
        dEmail.Text = email;
        dPhone.Text = phone;
        dDesignation.Text = designation;
    }
```

In above code the exception is raised at `dName.Text = name;` Bellow is the error description

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Same work is performed in my `show complete data` function but there the things are good, don't know what's happening in `update` function

**Update 1**

Bellow is my `insert employee` code

```
namespace AppwithDB.Resources
{
[Activity(Label = "insertEmployee")]
class insertEmployee : Activity
{
    EditText name, email, phone, designation;
    Button submitBtn;
    private SQLiteHelper dbHelper;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        //Create your app here 

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.insert);
        initialize();
        dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
        submitBtn.Click += submitBtn_Click;
    }


    private void submitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (name.Text.ToString().Equals("") || email.Text.ToString().Equals("")|| phone.Text.ToString().Equals("") || designation.Text.ToString().Equals(""))
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Fields Empty Found", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        }
        else
        {
            dbHelper.insertEmployee(name.Text.ToString(), email.Text.ToString(), phone.Text.ToString(), designation.Text.ToString());
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Data Stored Successfully", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            name.Text = " ";
            email.Text = " ";
            phone.Text = " ";
            designation.Text = " ";
        }
    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        name = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.empName);
        email = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.empEmail);
        phone = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.empPhone);
        designation = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.empDesignation);
        submitBtn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.insertEmpBtn);
    }
}}
```

**Update 2**

Bellow is the code for `update employee`

```
namespace AppwithDB.Resources
{
[Activity(Label = "updateEmployee")]
class updateEmployee:Activity
{
    ListView list; 
    EditText dName, dEmail, dPhone, dDesignation;
    String name, email, phone, designation;
    SQLiteHelper dbHelper;
    int click_Employee;
    Button upBtn;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.update);
        initialize();
        dbHelper = new SQLiteHelper(this);
        System.Collections.ArrayList dataList = dbHelper.getALLEmployeesData();
        string[] myArr = (string[])dataList.ToArray(typeof(string));
        list.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleExpandableListItem1, myArr);

        list.ItemClick += List_ItemClick;

        upBtn.Click += delegate
        {
            dbHelper.updateEmployeeInfo(click_Employee, dName.Text.ToString(), dEmail.Text.ToString(), dPhone.Text.ToString(), dDesignation.Text.ToString());
        };

    }

    private void initialize()
    {
        list = (ListView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.listView1);
        dName = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.eName);
        dEmail = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.eEmail);
        dPhone = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.ePhone);
        dDesignation = (EditText)FindViewById(Resource.Id.eDesignation);
        upBtn = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.updateEmploy);
    }
    void List_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        click_Employee = e.Position + 1;
        ICursor c = dbHelper.getSingleEntry(click_Employee);
        c.MoveToFirst();
        name = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_NAME));
        email = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_EMAIL));
        phone = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_PHONE));
        designation = c.GetString(c.GetColumnIndex(dbHelper.EMPLOYEE_DESIGNATION));
        dName.Text = name;
        dEmail.Text = email;
        dPhone.Text = phone;
        dDesignation.Text = designation;
    }


}}
```

**Update 3 :**

Bellow are the `xmls` of `complete_data` and `update`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:divider="#000"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Email" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ePhone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eDesignation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Designation" />
    </LinearLayout></ScrollView></LinearLayout>
```

Update xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:divider="#000"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/upName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Name" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/upEmail"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Email" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/upPhone"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Phone" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/upDesignation"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Designation" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/updateEmploy"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Update Employee" />
    </LinearLayout></ScrollView></LinearLayout>
```

For better understanding the sample code is given above.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: post your `LocalDatabase` code

Comment: only  `LocalDatabase` namespace code mean MainActivity.cs

Comment: @PavneetSingh kindly see the update 1

Comment: you didn't asign any variable to `dName`. In the lesson, you gave link to it is done this way: `dName = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.eName);`

Comment: sorry my bad , you have to post `insertEmployee.cs` please remove the `MainActivity`

Comment: @VladMatvienko i have done the same in initialize method

Comment: @PavneetSingh kindly see it again i have updated it

Comment: I can't see you initialize your `dName` in your `initialize()` method, sorry

Comment: @VladMatvienko in update 1 the code is for insert data now kindly see the update 2 you can see it there

Comment: is the error still int the same line - `dName.Text = name;`

Comment: @VladMatvienko if i comment it then the error raises with the next assign

Comment: ok, then my question is as follows: Are you sure that your `Resource.Id.eName` is an `EditText` in your layout XML?

Comment: @VladMatvienko no the `eName` is `TextView`, Actually the things would work like this, whenever i select a record from `update` interface the data should be fetched from `show complete data` and will display on the the `update` interface in `edit text` fields so i can edit them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127631/discussion-between-fasi-and-vlad-matvienko).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you use wrong `View` IDs. In your XML there is `upName`, and you are searching for `Resource.Id.eName`.
To fix a problem you need to change `Resource.Id.eName` to `Resource.Id.upName`